# The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c++, makefile

I have downloaded mingw32 and have it working except I have a problem. I do not want to have to create a new batch file inside the ming32 directory in order to have my program run, If it is possible I would like to just create a `Makefile` inside vscode and then have that run.

When running the .bat file with the same code as below in the makefile:

```
C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>g++ main.o matrix.o matrices.o helper.o -o exec 
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find matrix.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find matrices.o: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find helper.o: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>main.o: main.cpp 
'main.o:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>g++ -c main.cpp 

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>matrix.o: matrix.cpp 
'matrix.o:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>g++ -c matrix.cpp 

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>matrices.o: matrices.cpp 
'matrices.o:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>g++ -c matrices.cpp 

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>helper.o: helper.cpp 
'helper.o:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>g++ -c helper.cpp 

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>clean:
'clean:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Visual Studio\CS210\1-Assignment>rm *.o exec 
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[vscode project file explorer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x75Ed.png)

the contents of my `Makefile` are as follows:

```
exec:  main.o  matrix.o matrices.o helper.o
    g++ main.o matrix.o matrices.o helper.o -o exec

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

matrix.o: matrix.cpp
    g++ -c matrix.cpp

matrices.o: matrices.cpp
    g++ -c matrices.cpp

helper.o: helper.cpp
    g++ -c helper.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o exec
```

[vscode make setting : directory & path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9dcB.png)
directory - None
path - make

### Below is original post

Good day, I am trying to create a makefile for c++ inside vscode. When running the command 'make' from the terminal i get the following error message:

```
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have attempted to install MinGW twice. When installing MinGW I ran the command `mingw-get install mingw32-make` in shell, this worked. I then setup my system properties PATH, this also went pretty smoothly. I also created a .exe file inside MinGW bin directory with the following command inside `'mingw32-make.exe $*`.

When I returned to vscode I ran `make` again; however, this time I got the following error message:

```
Program 'make.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
+ make
+ ~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ make
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Some side info:

The program that I am trying to run is inside my onedrive (if that makes a difference) and vscode is installed into the default directory (C:).

I have some extensions installed for vscode, such as cmake etc.

c/c++
c/c++ extention pack
CMake
CMake Tools
Makefile Tools

I have tried installed CMake multiple times.
I have tried uninstalled CMake & Makefile Tools

Comment: Last time I installed Linux from scratch on a new system from the time I booted up a live image stick, to the time I booted a fully installed Linux was about thirty minutes. Another ten minutes to install the latest version of gcc, make, emacs, and a few other libraries. If it took you more than that to painfully try to cram Linux-originated software into an alien operating system, that they weren't originally designed for, and it's still not working correctly, perhaps you should consider cutting your losses and installing Linux?

Comment: Sounds like you did not follow the VSCode recommendations and install msys2 and have that install MinGW:  [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) If you had done this you would have make installed with MinGW and both would  be in the `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` folder.

Comment: You should post a separate question about the new issue you're having. Don't edit a second question on top of the first one. (And don't create a dummy `make.exe` manually, this is about the worst thing one can do here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install make from the msys2 terminal using

```
pacman -S make
```

Then add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to your `PATH`

Comment: Hello, I did this and it worked  for the most part. The problem is that I don't want to have to write a new batch script inside the mingw32 directory. I would like to create a makefile inside vscode and then have it run from there. 

I'm completely out of the scope of my understanding about this but basically this is what I want to be able to do:

Create a program
Create a 'Makefile' inside vscode
write 'make' inside vscode terminal
Have the 'Makefile' execute

I am going to add my makefile content in the post above... 

Please excuse me if im not making any sense

Comment: Side note: `usr/bin`, if in the PATH, must be after any other MSYS2 paths, such as `mingw64/bin, otherwise weird things can happen.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the answer is now a community wiki that others can maintain/improve, this information cannot be found in any official documentation from vscode or mingw or microsoft, so it has to exist here.